# Creating Diagonal top of the div using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project where I want to create a diagonal div using CSS like in this image:

[image]

Comment: I have tried this https://jsfiddle.net/rmhrzqh5/

Comment: I also tried this one https://jsfiddle.net/oocputgz/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Bootstrap and Transition Skew CSS Property https://jsfiddle.net/oocputgz/24/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="blog-post-image">
<img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/20ff17cabf.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" />
</div>
<div class="post-detail_container">
<div class="sperator"></div>
<div class="post-content">
<h3 class="post-title">
Hello World
</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS Styling:

```
.post-detail_container
{
    position:relative;   
}

#blog-items .item
{
    padding:0px 15px;
}
.sperator
{
   position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: skew(0, -7deg);
-moz-transform: skew(0, -7deg);
-ms-transform: skew(0, -7deg);
-o-transform: skew(0, -7deg);
transform: skew(0, -7deg);
background: red;
}
.post-content
{
    background-color:red;
    padding:15px 15px;
    min-height: 300px;
}

.post-title
{
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 88px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the css "clip path". It's pretty simple to understand.

```css
#shape {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 55%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 55%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<div id='shape'></div>
```

Comment: compatibility chart via caniuse.com: http://caniuse.com/#search=clippath

Answer (score 1):

```css
.myDiv {
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/739247958340698114/fVKY9fOv.jpg');
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.myDiv:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 4;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 800px solid red;
 border-left: 800px solid transparent;
 top: -40%;
 left: -50%;
 -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}

p {
 position: relative;
 top: 70%;
 z-index: 5;
 font-size: 35px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
 <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! code is working fine. Is it any way to done this without providing absolute position to .myDiv class? because I am using bootstrap its effecting the layout.

Comment: Thank you Shoaib your answer was helpful!

Comment: You are welcome Umar! Thank you for accepting the answer, appreciate that!

Comment: Check this I have created using bootstrap https://jsfiddle.net/oocputgz/ now its mobile friendly.