# How to implement a decorative block in the form of a triangle?

Tags: html, css

I train in the layout of the site and make up the page according to the layout, you need to make such a decorative part
[image]

I tried to do it with the help of pseudo before and make a triangle out of border and it seems like a triangle turns out, but it doesn't work to make such a shadow anymore, since it's all exactly a rectangular block for html. Well, it would be nice if someone suggested how this can be done)
This is how the current result looks like
[image]

Comment: Show what you have tried so we may assist you in fixing it.  Some effort is expected here on this site (include your HTML and CSS attempt methinks)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating Diagonal top of the div using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604505/creating-diagonal-top-of-the-div-using-css)

Comment: Have you looked into CSS clip-path?